Shell/bash: Can I create a file descriptor to an existing file without emptying the file?
Context: I have cursory bash experience. I do not fully get file descriptors, just some basic usage. Trying to create a setup script. Most done, but a few "kinks" remain.
So here is a newbie question on logging and file descriptors!
Goal(s):

Log all executions of the script to a daily logfile.
If script is executed multiple times one day, logfile is appended to.

I do not want several logfiles per day, one rotation per day is plenty.


I output

(a) basic/overview/main info to the console, and (using e g echo [...] >&3.
(b) all "details" go to the logfile (all standard output, echo). (See sample script.)


Avoid log function: I would love to avoid having special log functions to call, but maybe that is the only way...

Problem/obstacle: When I create the file descriptor, it seems the logfile is reset/emptied.
Example: Again, see sample script below. First cat (row 3) indeed outputs previous contents of the logfile. But after setting up the file descriptors for logging on row 5, the cat on row 7 always outputs nothing.

Question(s):

(A) Can I use this approach and somehow create a file descriptor for an existing file, and avoid it "resetting"/emptying the existing file of its previous contents?
(B) If that approach can not work, is there an alternative way that accomplishes my goals?

Sample script
LOG_FILE="./$(date -u +%Y%m%dTZ).log.txt"
touch $LOG_FILE
cat $LOG_FILE
echo -----------------------
exec 3>&1 1>"$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 #TODO: suspect this file descriptor creation resets existing file. Investigate if/how this can be avoided.
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++ >&3
cat $LOG_FILE >&3 # this is always empty
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++ >&3
read -t 2
echo "${blu}=================================================="
echo Logging some. Time: $(date -Iseconds) 
echo "==================================================${end}"


I have of course searched to try and find a solution, but for this problem it seems I cannot find any good discussions at all. Lots on file descriptors, but I have not managed to find anyone asking this question. I may be using the wrong keywords, ofc. I found this related question, and others a bit like that.
Thanks alot for reading my question!

Are you looking for 1>>"$LOG_FILE"? (The 1 is default for output redirections, btw, so just >>"$LOG_FILE")

I especially like how you structured your post into preamble, goal, problem, question. That's nice to read!

Thanks @MarcusMüller!
@muru: Thanks, yes that sounds promising. Meanwhile, continued searching found this which seems to be also about >> append, what I glean from your comment. Will test that a bit now!

Yes, duh. That seems to solve it. It feels like I already did this many years ago. A sign of age that you run into the same things over again...
Thanks @muru. If you want to provide a proper answer, I can mark it.

@MarcusWiderberg another trick is to simply always append to the same file (without date in its name), and use (meaning: configure! Your system is almost certainly using it for other logs already) logrotate to rename the log on a daily basis.

I second the opinion of @marcus-müller: very good way to ask a question, very structured. This is still too rare, we do appreciate a lot the effort you made into creating it.

Odd, there is a statement added above that contends that this is a duplicate of two questions (1 "What are the shell's control and redirection operators?", and 2 "Bash IO redirection, open & close 'fd', can someone explain?" which are also about file descriptors, but no more closely answer this question. Surprising, maybe an AI thing that saw a remote relation?

To clarify: After asking I found another question that is actually close to this question (not just that its about file descriptors in general) which I stated and linked to above in the third comment. But, since that question is so sparsely worded, and in fact asks about a different file descriptor problem, I did not find it. But it had the simple solution in the second answer. Again, it is: "Bash redirection: append to a file descriptor (2>>&1)"

You have several options, but those have to be >> file instead of > file in order to not "clobber" that file.
For exemple, if you need to redirect STDOUT and STDERR inside your script to that logfile, you could use exec lines :
exec 1>>logfile.log # fd 1 now points to file logfile.log, without clobbering it
exec 2>&1           # fd 2 now points to where fd 1 points now, ie logfile.log 
 # (note : just 2>&1, not 2>>&1 : m>&n just "copies" the fd "n" destination into fd "m")

For exemple:
$ cat script.bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

log="./logfile.log" # better to place a /absolute/path here, otherwise it goes to whatever the caller's current working directory ($PWD) is
exec 3>&1
exec 4>&2

function logsize_info() {
    printf "  == %s: the file %s has : %s lines.\n" "$1" "${log}" "$( wc -l < "${log}" )" >&3 # to STDOUT
}

logsize_info "before redirections"
date    # should appear on STDOUT

exec 1>>"${log}"  # now fd 1 points to "${log}" file
logsize_info "after redirecting fd 1"

date    # should go to "${log}"
logsize_info "after date"

ls -d /something_inexistant_1 # should appear on STDERR as fd 2 still goes to STDERR
logsize_info "after listing /something_inexistant_1"

exec 2>&1      # now fd 2 points to the same place fd1 currently goes to : "${log}" file
logsize_info "after redirecting fd 2"

echo foo                            # to ${log}
echo bar                            # to ${log}
echo baz                            # to ${log}
ls -d /something_inexistant_2       # to ${log}
ls -d /something_inexistant_3 2>&4  # to STDERR
logsize_info "4 more lines should have appeared: 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', and 'an error msg about /something_inexistant_2'"

exec 1>&3 # reconnecting fd 1 to STDOUT (otherwise the following "cat" will output an error that Input=Output!)
exec 2>&4 # reconnecting fd 2 to STDERR
printf "Content of \${log} (= %s ) :\n" "${log}"
cat "${log}"

$ printf "%s\n" "original" "lines" > ./logfile.log
$ ./script.bash
  == before redirections: the file ./logfile.log has : 2 lines.
mar.  9 juil. 2024 14:11:49
  == after redirecting fd 1: the file ./logfile.log has : 2 lines.
  == after date: the file ./logfile.log has : 3 lines.
ls: cannot access /something_inexistant: No such file or directory
  == after listing /something_inexistant_1: the file ./logfile.log has : 3 lines.
  == after redirecting fd 2: the file ./logfile.log has : 3 lines.
ls: cannot access /something_inexistant_3: No such file or directory
  == 4 more lines should have appeared: 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', and 'an error msg about /something_inexistant_2': the file ./logfile.log has : 7 lines.
Content of ${log} (= ./logfile.log ) :
original
lines
mar.  9 juil. 2024 14:11:49
foo
bar
baz
ls: cannot access /something_inexistant_2: No such file or directory
$


I think you can use 2>>&1 instead of 2>&1, it just doesn't make a difference...

@ilkkachu : it may be, but I preferred to point out that it isn't the same mechanism, ie it does not further affect the way the file was originally opened with (during the exec 1>>the_file)

Wow, what a fantastic answer, starts with "the answer" in one short and concise sentence and then explains further with a wonderfully commented example. Thanks!
